# Particle Effect trigger when moving character in Unity

Tags: unity, particles

I'm very new to Unity, and I'm trying to figure out how to make it so particle effect for my player is triggered only when the player moves forward, anyone have advice how to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? We can help with any issue you encountered while trying to implement your solution.

Comment: I've linked this post to a [previous question about how to do this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/198850/39518). If you have any trouble implementing the solution described there, please edit your question to clarify what you've tried and where it's going wrong, and we can re-open it for answers specific to that issue.